# Not able to change value of input field after setting the initial value manually in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am working on an application where I pass variable values in a Navlink using state from one component to the other and set its initial values equal to that of the passed values but I am not able to alter the input field value after setting the initial value. The route is already defined in app.js

My code for parent class

```js
class Parent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={id:2}
      } 
    render(){
       return(
<NavLink to={{
       pathname: '/Child',
      state: {
        id: this.state.id
      }
     }}>Edit</NavLink>
        ))}
```

Code for child class

```js
class Child extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

          this.state = {id:this.props.location.state.id}
          this.setId = this.setId.bind(this)
}
 setId(e){
         this.setState=({id:e.target.value})
      }
render(){

        return(
         <div>
            <form>
            <label>Id</label>
            <input value={this.state.id} onClick={this.setId.bind(this)}  type="text"/><br/>
</form>
</div>
)}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onChange should be

```
onChange={this.setId}
```

setId should be

```
setId(e){
     this.setState({id:e.target.value});
}
```